# Urn problem without replacement, optimizing number of draws

Tags: probability, combinatorics, optimization

Let's say an urn has three types of balls: a,b,c. Assume that each ball gives us a different dollar amount, x,y,0. The first two give x and y(respectively) and the last one gives 0. Assume that each draw costs d. I decide in the beginning how many I will draw and then do so.  So I will only pay for the first draw if $E[drawing]-d>0$. Now assume this inequality is true for the first draw, how many draws should I pay for? Clearly, I should not pay for infinite draws because the maximum revenue is $ax+by$.

I am trying to think of a way of conceptualizing this problem, the number of draws need not necessarily be discreet.

Comment: If you have perfect information about all the draw, and can make decision before each draw, then you just compute the expected value and test the inequality before each draw.

Comment: @BGM Of course if I make the game dynamic it's simpler :), but that's a different problem.

Comment: You have used $c$ for the number of balls worth zero and for the cost of drawing.  Please use different symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used $c$ for the number of balls worth zero and for the cost of drawing. 
 I will use $d$ for the cost of a draw.  If you have to decide at the beginning how many draws to make, they all have the same expectation.  If it is negative, don't draw at all.  If it is positive, draw all the balls.  Your profit for drawing all the balls is $ax+by-(a+b+c)d$.  The expectation of a single draw is $\frac {ax+by}{a+b+c}-d$.  If either (so both) of these is positive, draw them all.

Comment: @Ross_Millikan Does that not seem strange? We either pay for all the draws or none of the draws? No chance we will draw an intermediate amount?

Comment: It doesn’t seem strange at all to me. All the draws have equal value, so you want all of them or none. For one that bothers people even more, search for simple and bet in my answers.